# How to work locally on a copy of my wordpress?

Tags: installation, localhost

I would like to redesign my wordpress site. I thought I do that first locally to get a feeling for it. So I compressed my live wordpress directory and transfered it locally. And took a backup of the database and transfered it locally as well.

I restored from both files the exact copy of my live wordpress on my lcoal machine. Going to 127.0.0.1 works fine. But all the links still point to my BlogSite.com rather than 127.0.0.1.

Is there any quick "fix" for that? Or any other strategy how I could achieve working locally on my website?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You may first need to modify the `wp-config.php` file for using the local database.

Then use the [`Search and Replace`](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-and-replace/) plugin to replace all your live site links with the localhost links. Example: If your live site url is: `http://mysite.com/`, replace it with `http://localhost/mysite/`. This will also replace the urls for pages and posts like: `http://mysite.com/post` with `http://localhost/mysite/post`.

Note: You'll still need to manually update any links (and image urls) in the widgets, because S and R doesn't replace them.

Comment: Thanks, I have named the localdb like my live site, so there was no need to edit wp-config.php.  I searched and replaced the site reference in the sql dump. But permalinks dont seem to work yet...

Comment: That's because the manual search and replace doesn't work completely! All the urls stored in the `wp_options` table are searialized, and a manual search and replace won't change them! Upload your sql dump again, and use the plugin I mentioned above.

Comment: I have reuploaded my dump file without any changes. Then I installed http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-and-replace/. Did teh search and replace in there. It still doesnt work. :(

Comment: Not even the login?

Comment: login is working :)

Comment: Ahh, that is strange! I use Search and Replace for all site migrations and it works fine. Can't see why it fails for you!

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to add a line in your `/etc/hosts` file, like this:

```
1.2.3.4 www.myblog.example.org
```

The first line should be the IP of tour TEST machine, the second one is your blog's DNS name.

After adding this line in `/etc/hosts` "everyone" in your test machine will "know" that `www.myblog.example.org` is at `1.2.3.4`.

You need to change nothing in the database or wordpress settings.

And you can comment/uncomment this line at any time.

Comment: This seems indeed like a clean alternative.  No need to mess around with the dump file.  While this solution in it self work, the permalink problem is still there. :(

Comment: @Kave There should not be any issue with permalinks. Check apache's settings, installed/enabled modules, httpd.conf etc. If you "clone" everything (apache, WP, wpdb, settings etc-etc), you should get *the same* box, a "clone".  A line in `/etc/hosts` simply "workarounds" resolver's behavior. This way works for me perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace all occurences of live website for the local path in your DB dump and in template files (if there are any hardcored urls, i hope not ;) ). Moving WP from server to server goes quite fine, I always copy everything from FTP, then do the database dump (*.sql file for example, you can use for instance phpmyadmin or whatever you prefer), replace all urls for the local ones, import this file in your local DB and change wp-config.php to use correct database settings. So having a "snapshot" of live page can be done in a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks I have exactly done that. But permalinks doesnt seem to work. the .htaccess is still inside my /var/www/mySite  so why doesn't it work?

Comment: so try to go to Options page in WP admin and rebuild all permalinks structure, if it helps?

Comment: ok, I went to WpAdmin -> Settings --> Permalinks and saved it as it was. It saved. I go back to homepage and do refresh. Still all permalinks broken. Any other tip? :)